# Asp.net core: How to use appSettings for a particular environment

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, appsettings

In .NET 6.0 WebApi application

I have the following two files:
appSettings.json
appSettings.Linux.json

I want the application to use appSettings.Linux.json when running in linux environment. The following is the code that I have tried so far but unfortunately it is not working. It is still accessing appSettings.json file while running in linux environment.

```
    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
    {
        IConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                            .AddJsonFile("appSettings.Linux.json" , optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
        builder.Build();
    }
```

I am adding a new builder as follows
[image]

Comment: what kind of application it is. console app or web api ? and if web api which version of .NET 5 or 6?

Comment: net 6. WebAPi. updating inthe question as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in .NET 6, you can do like this.

```
if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
{
    builder.Environment.EnvironmentName = "Linux";
    builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appSettings.Linux.json");
}
```

and then it will override all the configuration values.

appsettings.Linux.json
[image]

accessing value from Configuration
[image]

Updated answer based on feedback.

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                {
                    if (RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux))
                    {
                        config.AddJsonFile("appSettings.Linux.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
                    }
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Comment: not working in my case still reading from normal appSettings

Comment: are you creating  ConfigurationBuilder again or using like i have done.

Comment: Yes i am creating it again

Comment: why do you need to create again. and it is only local in your code block it is not getting assigned to actual configuration.

Comment: configure method is not correct place to create configuration.

Comment: On startup's construction im injecting the Iconfiguration interface from Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Abstractions. We have no way of adding in it the json file AFAIK, thats why adding

Comment: where shall i do it then

Comment: @Sana: I have updated the ans. if you are using old way of program.cs then you can update it there.